# error checking in model

Tags: mysql, sql, model-view-controller

How do I do error checking, in my model? For instance if my procedure adds a record I want to return true if not I want to return false. Do I need to do a count on the records in the table before and after the procedure then compare them which is the best way to do this?

```
function add_student($SECTION_ID, $STUDENT_ID)

{

$this->db->query("call add_student('$SECTION_ID','$STUDENT_ID')");

}


function drop_student($SECTION_ID, $STUDENT_ID)
{

$this->db->query("call drop_student('$SECTION_ID','$STUDENT_ID')");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your database is mysql

Use [FOUND_ROWS( )](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)  to find rows affected after executing the select statement in the procedure

Or You could use [ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) function to find the number of records after insert statement

Comment: Thanks, did not know about this. DO you mean to use this in my stored procedure or in my model?